# ¿Cómo generar un script para validar que un archivo de texto contenga una palabra en cada línea?

Tags: bash, shell

Tengo un archivo llamado *ip.log* dentro de de este archivo está lo siguiente:

```
192.168.5.x OK
192.168.3.x OK
192.168.8.x OK
```

Necesito un script que busque en cada línea si tiene la palabra "OK" y luego imprima un resultado.

Si el archivo tuviera algo diferente a "OK" en alguna línea deberá imprimir otro resultado.

Esto fue lo que hice:

```
filename="/home/ip.log" 
while read -r line
do
readline=$line
if [[ $readline == *OK* ]] 
then
    echo "BIEN"
else
    echo "MAL"
fi
done < "$filename"
```

Pero me da una salida de línea por línea, únicamente ocupo un único resultado si lo que esta al final es diferente de "OK" en todo el archivo.

Actualización: Necesito contar las palabras que salgan en "MAL" e imprimirlas en pantalla por ejemplo "10 MAL" tengo alguna idea con awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
filename="/home/ip.log"
result_output="BIEN"
while read -r line
do
  readline=$line
  if [[ $readline != *"OK"* ]]
  then
    result_output="MAL"
  fi
done < "$filename"
echo $result_output
```

Lo que se hace es que si no se encuentra el "OK" en la línea, cambia `result_output` a "MAL" y al terminar el ciclo, imprime que está mal, sólo una vez ya que el último `echo` no está dentro del ciclo.

Como el código anterior va a seguir iterando hasta la última línea del archivo y si se encuentra más coincidencias, sólo va a volver a poner `result_output` a "MAL" una y otra vez a pesar que ya tenga ese valor, mejor romper el ciclo a la primera que encuentre que "OK" no está en la línea.

```
filename="/home/ip.log"
result_output="BIEN"
while read -r line
do
  readline=$line
  if [[ $readline != *"OK"* ]]
  then
    result_output="MAL"
    break
  fi
done < "$filename"
echo $result_output
```

Comment: Tu solución funciono como esperaba te lo agradezco, aun estoy en los primeros pasos en bash. Ahora estoy tratando de contar todos los "MAL" cuando se encuentren e imprimir ejemplo "8 MAL" sera con awk?

Comment: Sí, se puede con `awk` o simplemente le pones un contador al código que incremente cada que llega al `if`

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente a la solución que ya tienes, puedes usar `awk` que tiene la ventaja de poder indicar la columna (en este caso la segunda) sobre la cual hacer la búsqueda y además poder usar expresiones regulares:

```
awk '$2 !~ /OK/ {error = 1;exit;} END {if(error == 1){print "MAL"}else{print "BIEN"}}' /home/ip.log
```

Por defecto `awk` separa los datos por blancos, por lo que con `$2` hacemos referencia a dicha columna, sobre la cual evaluamos negando ('!~')  el patrón `OK`, en caso de ocurrencia se ejecuta el bloque `{error = 1;exit;}`, es decir, seteamos una variable `error` y terminamos con la lectura del archivo. El bloque `END` se ejecuta siempre al finalizar el script `awk`, dónde chequeamos la variable `error` e imprimimos el texto adecuado